# RPG vs. RPG in tags on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

Okay, this might be annoying only to me, but I have to ask the question. I work on the IBM i (aka iSeries, aka AS/400) and the primary language on that machine is RPG. Questions about that language are tagged `[rpg]`. There have also been questions on SO about role-playing games tagged as `[rpg]`. This can cause confusion for both sides. What can/should be done to clear this confusion?

Comment: This will become an even bigger problem if anyone starts asking questions about [rocket-propelled grenades](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket-propelled_grenade)... I can see it now: " *As a programmer*, what RPG do you like to use on people who try to parse HTML with regular expressions?"

Comment: @gnos: HAHA! love it!

Comment: Obviously programmers of action games might need help in programming the [weapons](http://dukenukem.wikia.com/wiki/RPG), so we will need `[rpg-game-genre]` and `[rpg-game-weapon]`. Also, while we're at it, lets establish `[java-island]` for those programming **on** [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java). :)

Comment: There is no fundamental problem with dual use tags. Until real confusion results, let it be...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the moment, there are only 39 total questions tagged `[rpg]` [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/RPG). They're pretty evenly split between games and the RPG language.

I think the real problem here is that `[rpg]` is being used for games at all. Of the few questions that are tagged `[rpg]` and are not about the language, there don't seem to be any that couldn't just as well be tagged more generically as `[game]`; in other words, it doesn't matter whether or not the game is role-playing. But even that's moot, as game development now has its own SE site.

My proposal is to manually wipe out the `[rpg]` tag on game questions, retagging to `[game]` where appropriate, and leaving the tag untouched on RPG language questions.

EDIT (response to comments):
The point I'm trying to make is that any question which deserves the tag `[rpg]` doesn't belong on SO in the first place. If you have a C++ question and you just happen to be working on a role-playing game, that's fine, but don't tag your question `[rpg]`. If the fact that you're working on a role-playing game *matters* to the question, then the question probably should be asked on Game Dev SE, not SO.

As a side benefit, this leaves `[rpg]` to refer to the language unambiguously. And with that being the case, there's no need for creating complex synonym trees or separate `[rpg-game]` or `[rpg-lang]` tags.

Of course, this will change again once rocket-propelled grenade developers start using the site, but when that happens, I'm out of here, you're on your own.

Comment: @Popular Demand: however, then the tag will be improperly used on RPG game questions when they should only be used for RPG-lang as you are proposing.  We should though, have both tags, RPG, and RPG-Language, so that there is no confusion...

Comment: @studiohack Unfortunately, using RPG and RPG-Language doesn't pass the "idiot in a hurry test". Someone posting a question about the language is going to see RPG and select it because they don't really care about the tag, they care about getting their question answered. RPG-Games and RPG-Language would be better, IMHO.

Comment: therein lies our problem...

Comment: I agree with @Michael Todd, completely removing [RPG] and making it [RPG-Games] and [RPG-Language] would make it more obvious that there is a choice. A person working on an RPG game will still use [RPG] if offered as a choice and hopefully cuts moderator time overall.

Comment: RPG-Game is even worse than RP-Game, and the latter is already bad. It'll avoid confusion but it'll make us look like uneducated loaches, namely to the people who would actually need to use the tag. And for the otherwise, I agree with Pop that it isn't necessary as a tag on a question for SO.

Comment: @Grace, +1, but... will it really make us look like uneducated carplike freshwater cyprinoid fish of the family _Cobitidae_, of Eurasia and Africa, which have long narrow bodies and barbels around their mouths? (dictionary.com)

Comment: @Grace Note: But I imagine you feel that way only because these are tags, not paragraphs. We can't use a tag called "RPG-(this-one-is-for-role-playing-games)" because that would be silly. More descriptive, but silly. (And, BTW, do _you_ care if gamers look at us as uneducated loaches?)

Comment: True, the original answer here is a good solution. Especially with a game development site. The fact that a question is for an role playing means nothing for the solution of the programming question. While the question being for the RPG language does have meaning. How does this get implemented. Someone going through and retagging things?

Comment: @Michael Being a gamer, yes, I do care. Second, why not [role-playing-game], if we had to have it? It's unambiguous and non-redundant.

Comment: @Mike It's going to require people to watch for it, yes. But given the small quantity, it's something the RPG language community should be able to monitor as they see questions come up with the tag.

Comment: @Grace Note because people are lazy. Also, what value does it add to the question by saying it is for a role playing game in the scope of SO?

Comment: @Grace Note: Agreed, except that most gamers think "RPG" not "role-playing-games." Tough call. (And I'm a gamer, too, and _still_ don't care if other gamers call me an unedumacated loach.)

Comment: @Mike I don't think it has value, as indicated in my first comment.

Comment: @Mike, yes, since there are only about a dozen questions, a manual retag would be the way to go here. Just so you know for the future though, the mods can do mass retags and the admins might even -- given a _really_ compelling reason -- poke at the database manually.

Comment: We can do mass retags, but we can't clear tags anymore (there has to be a target tag), and it won't work on something ambiguous like this anyway since then we'd clear it from all of the language questions as well.

Comment: Okay, if this is okay with the moderators, I'll watch [rpg] and retag role playing games [rpg] as [game].

Answer (score 0):

We could have

- Role Playing Games as RPG
- The language RPG as RPG-Lang or RPG-Language

Comment: RP-Games is not a standard abbreviation of "role-playing games": unless someone read this exact topic, they'd never in a million years use `[RP-Games]` to tag or search for questions about role-playing games.

Comment: Although the dropdown would popup and show it, but I agree there.

Comment: @studio Is that a Wyoming cowboy?

Comment: @Mark: what about tagging the games as RPG-Games? and RPG-Lang or RPG-Language?  That way, the drop down would show both of these, and they can choose...

Comment: @NullUserException: How did you guess? :-)

Comment: We beat the Cowboys in a football game a couple of weeks ago

Comment: @studiohack I like that idea.

Comment: @studio Based on [the tag usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rpg), it seems people using it for the RPG language are the minority, and "RPG games" is redundant. I'd say `[RPG]` should be used for the game genre and `[RPG-language]` should be used for the programming language.

Comment: @Mark: Okay, I edited my answer to reflect your suggestions...That is actually a better idea, like you said, the RPG is more widely used for games...

Comment: I had at one time gone through and re-tagged some to RPGLE, but really that isn't a solution. RPG LE is technically a version of RPG. There are several more questions in RPGLE as well. Very few questions are not about the RPG LE version. Even that could cause confusion though.